# problems installing foundation-cli on a mac

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm new to `foundation-cli` and already searched for in the forum..

I tried to install it on my late 2012 iMac several times always getting warnings and errors. Is there anything I can do about it or do I have to keep on using foundation without the cli?

**Installing the foundation-cli i get this message:**

```
**(sudo npm install -g foundation-cli
Password:)**

npmWARNdeprecated bower@1.8.4: We don't recommend using Bower for new projects. Please consider Yarn and Webpack or Parcel. You can read how to migrate legacy project here: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/

npmWARNdeprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js

/usr/local/bin/foundation -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/foundation-cli/bin/foundation.js

+ foundation-cli@2.2.5

added 324 packages from 530 contributors in 12.579s
```

and afterwards **foundation new** brings this up:

```
foundation new

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/foundation-cli/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:54

throw err;

^



Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/ferdinand/.config/configstore/bower-github.json'

You don't have access to this file.



at Object.openSync (fs.js:439:3)

at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:344:35)

at Configstore.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/foundation-cli/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:35:26)

at new Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/foundation-cli/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:28:45)

at readCachedConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/foundation-cli/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:19:23)

at defaultConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/foundation-cli/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:11:12)

at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/foundation-cli/node_modules/bower/lib/index.js:16:32)

at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)

at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
```

Comment: For the permission error did you use `sudo` to run the `foundation new` command? That may be your issue since using `sudo` will grant admin rights to every step of the process.

Comment: On my mac I end up using sudo every time I do things like this (installing node packages for development).

Comment: Check version requirements here especially Node: https://github.com/zurb/foundation-cli. I reckon your Node is super old.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I already tried the 'foundation new' command with sudo, but there comes up a warning not to do this because i could be dangerous and nothing happens. The latest version of Node is installed ...

Answer (score 0):

You could iron out the permission errors to install the CLI but I suggest doing a manual install which is actually just 2 steps.

You can clone the template the CLI uses: (change projectname to whatever name you want)

`git clone https://github.com/zurb/foundation-zurb-template projectname`

Then cd into that project and run

`yarn`

Comment: Thanks a lot rafibomb - i tried the manual installation and it worked well so far. I didn't find it at my research before my post.

Comment: To update to the latest version of foundation (in case there is one in the future) do i use clone again or is there a smarter way?

Comment: Just run `git pull`. Please mark this answer as solution.